# Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler activity with Dialog is not starting

Tags: kotlin, android-activity, error-handling, dialog, android-jetpack-compose

I want to show a Dialog to the user when the application crash with an unhandled error.

I started looking for a solution and found I should use the Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler

Found this related stackoverflow [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32229170/catch-all-possible-android-exception-globally-and-reload-application) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13416879/show-a-dialog-in-thread-setdefaultuncaughtexceptionhandler)

I tried the solution by [smirkingman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/338101/smirkingman) in [link1] but the activity does not start or is not created. It pass the "context.startActivity(intent)" and goes to the "finally" segment.  I added debug stop marks inside the class functions but never stop in any.  I now is not an internal error because it goes over the "catch" without stopping. I added a "TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5)" before exit to allow the Dialog to show.

Reading on [link2] there is a statement by [eldjon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3747404/eldjon) that says it can't be done on Android 4 and over. I will like to confirm the statement so I don't continue wasting more efforts on this Intent.

This is the code I tried:

Manifest //////

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.HouseInventory"
    tools:targetApi="31">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.HouseInventory">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".ErrorReportActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.HouseInventory">
    </activity>
</application>
```

MainActivity ///////

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    Log.d("test", "Entered MainActivity")
    
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(MyUncaughtExceptionHandler(applicationContext))
    setContent {
        HouseInventoryTheme {
            // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
            Surface(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
            ) {
// Content code
```

Error Handler //////

```
private var oldHandler: Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler? = null

class MyUncaughtExceptionHandler(context: Context) : Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {
private val context: Context
private val defaultHandler: Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler?

init {
    this.context = context//.applicationContext
    defaultHandler = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()
}

override fun uncaughtException(thread: Thread, exception: Throwable) {
    try {
        val sw = StringWriter()
        exception.printStackTrace(PrintWriter(sw))
        val intent = Intent(context, ErrorReportActivity::class.java)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        intent.putExtra("error_message", "Woops. An unexpected error occurred")
        intent.putExtra("stack_trace", sw.toString())

        // Start the new activity directly without using startActivity()
        if (context is Activity) {
            context.startActivity(intent)
        } else {
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
            context.startActivity(intent)
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    } finally {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5)
        System.exit(1)
    }
}
}

class ErrorReportActivity : Activity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    handleUncaughtException()
}

private fun handleUncaughtException() {
    val error: String = intent.getStringExtra("error_message")!!
    val stackTrace:String = intent.getStringExtra("stack_trace")!!

    showDialogWithStackTrace(error, stackTrace)
}

//@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
private fun showDialogWithStackTrace(error: String, stackTrace: String) {
    val dialog = Dialog(this)
    dialog.setCancelable(true)

    val dialogLayout = LinearLayout(this)
    dialogLayout.orientation = LinearLayout.VERTICAL
    dialogLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE)
    dialog.setContentView(dialogLayout)
    val errorTextView = createTextView(error,10f,Color.RED)
    val stackTraceTextView = createTextView(stackTrace, 8f, Color.BLACK)

    /*//set the properties for button
    val btnTag = Button(this)
    btnTag.layoutParams =
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
    btnTag.text = "Ok"
    btnTag.id = (1..512).random()*/

    dialogLayout.addView(errorTextView)
    dialogLayout.addView(stackTraceTextView)
    //add button to the layout
    //dialogLayout.addView(btnTag)

    dialog.show()

}

private fun createTextView(text: String, textSize: Float, textColor: Int): TextView {
    val textView = TextView(this)
    textView.text = text
    textView.textSize = textSize
    textView.setTextColor(textColor)
    textView.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
    return textView
}
}
```